# Logging all attempts to .txt file in Java

Tags: java, authentication, logging

I am trying to write a simple login application that logs all attempts at logging in to a .txt file. Currently my application will only log what the last attempt was. Any pointers?

Here is some of my code:

```
public boolean authenticate(String user, String pword) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("Test")
            && pword.equals("password")) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}

public static void accessLog(String username) {
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

    // declaring variables of log and initializing the buffered writer
    String log = "Username: " + username + "   Attempted login timestamp: " + timestamp + "\n";
    BufferedWriter writer = null;

    //write the log variable using the bufferedWriter to log.txt
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Log.txt"));
        writer.write(log);
    } //print error message if there is one
    catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("File IO Exception" + io.getMessage());
    } //close the file
    finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        } //print error message if there is one
        catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Issue closing the file." + io.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a problem to add one more parameter?

```
`boolean isSuccess = authenticate(user, password);
 accessLog(username, isSuccess);

public static void accessLog(String username, boolean isSuccess) {
//code here
}
`
```

Comment: Ok, I get that part but how do I make the log file document every attempt to login? Currently I can only get the last attempt to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue with this:

```
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Log.txt",true));
```